# Fetch users posts count in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I have for me hard but for you very easy problem.I have jobs table and users table and i want to fetch users jobs count from database.

here is my jobs table columns
[image]

here is my users table columns
[image]

and i want to fetch users posted jobs count.

Comment: I don't understand your problem

Comment: i just want to get users posted jobs count from jobs table

Comment: do you have user's id or just name?

Comment: you can see on picture there have user_id in jobs table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is fixed by myself.I added this code in my jobs model

here is my model code

```
    public static function jobCountOfUsers(int $id)
{
    return self::select('id','user_id')
        ->where('user_id', $id)
        ->get()
        ->count();
}
```

here is my blade

```
<a href="{{ url('/users-posts/'. $jobDetail->user_id) }}">{{ \App\Jobs::jobCountOfUsers($jobDetail->user_id) }}</span></a>
```

i hope this code will help to another developers

Answer (score 2):

You can use `count` and `join` to achieve the same

```
 $users = DB::table('users')
         ->select("users.id", DB::raw("count(jobs.id) as total") )
         ->join('jobs', 'users.id', '=', 'jobs.user_id')
         ->groupBy("jobs.user_id")
         ->get();
```

Reference:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#aggregates

Comment: thanks you for the answer but i tryed use this code before but its just getting all users count. i want to fetch only my posts count. for example you have 2 posted jobs i have 10 posted jobs. like this

Comment: i got this error   Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::selectRaw() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\Users\nasib\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\job_announcement\app\Http\Controllers\JobDetailController.php on line 31

Comment: SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "count(jobs" LINE 1: select "users"."id", "count(jobs"."id)" as "total" from "use... ^ (SQL: select "users"."id", "count(jobs"."id)" as "total" from "users" inner join "jobs" on "user_id" = "jobs"."user_id")

Comment: you need to add single quote around jobs.id.. try my code now

Comment: same error.....

Comment: "count('jobs.id') as total" we have error here

Comment: SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "count('jobs" LINE 1: select "users"."id", "count('jobs"."id')" as "total" from "u... ^ (SQL: select "users"."id", "count('jobs"."id')" as "total" from "users" inner join "jobs" on "jobs"."user_id" = "users"."id")

Comment: now i got this error....   SQLSTATE[42803]: Grouping error: 7 ERROR: column "users.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function LINE 1: select "users"."id", count(jobs.id) as total from "users" in... ^ (SQL: select "users"."id", count(jobs.id) as total from "users" inner join "jobs" on "users"."id" = "jobs"."user_id")

Comment: Updated my code ..Try now

Comment: now is this error  SQLSTATE[42803]: Grouping error: 7 ERROR: column "users.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function LINE 1: select "users"."id", count(jobs.id) as total from "users" in... ^ (SQL: select "users"."id", count(jobs.id) as total from "users" inner join "jobs" on "users"."id" = "jobs"."user_id" group by "jobs"."user_id")

Answer (score 0):

```
$users = DB::table('users')
         ->select("users.id", DB::raw("count(jobs.id) as total"))
         ->join('jobs', 'jobs.user_id', '=', 'users.id' )
         ->get()
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42803]: Grouping error: 7 ERROR: column "users.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function LINE 1: select "users"."id", count(jobs.id) as total from "users" in... ^ (SQL: select "users"."id", count(jobs.id) as total from "users" inner join "jobs" on "jobs"."user_id" = "users"."id")

Comment: $users = DB::table('users')
         ->select("users.id", DB::raw("count(jobs.id) as total"))
         ->join('jobs', 'users.id', '=', 'jobs.user_id'  )
         ->get()                                    please check any error give me

Comment: Please update your answer if you need to, but don't post changed code as comments. It's too hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would use a Model, as it makes your code readable in the long term.

Create a Model for your `jobs`. For example

```
 protected $fillable = [
     'name'
      ...
     'user_id'
  ]
```

Then create an eloquent. This basically joins two tables by an ID.

```
public function User() { 
   return $this->hasOne('App\User','id','user_id');
}
```

In your controller/job you can then do

```
Jobs::whereHas('User', function ($query) {
    $query->where('user_id', '=', $user_id);
})->get()->count();
```

Alternatively you can do `Jobs::query()->where('user_id',$user_id)->get()->count()`